# Access to the xamarin.form Android 10 sd card

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-external-storage

I have to access the files on the external sd card, but I can't because an error is returned.

How can I activate the authorization to access the SD card?

My code:

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var filesPath = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDocuments).Path;
   var files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(filesPath);
}
```

The error is:

> Access to the path '/ storage / emulated / 0 / Documents' is denied.

Comment: Can you access file using File Explorer?  With smart cards I usually recommend 3 steps 1) First make sure you can get full access using file explorer.  This makes sure you have the drivers installed properly and you have the certificate to unlock. 2) Unlock card using file explorer and then write your code to read/write device.  This makes sure you have the read/write card working with the device.  Devices can be different sizes (16,32,64) and this makes sure you read write methods are addressing the card properly 3) Finally write code to unlock card in c#. This is hard to do before step 2.

Answer (score 0):

Have you requested the runtime permission?

Before 6.0, the permission system of Android was always used by users to request authorization from users during installation, so the app may obtain some private information without users' knowledge after installation.

In order to solve this problem, Google improved the permission system in Android 6.0, and changed some permissions related to users' privacy to request authorization from users dynamically when the app runs.

you could refer to [RuntimePermission](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/requesting-runtime-permissions-in-android-marshmallow/)